# how to use the phones defualt camera

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

im trying to use my iphones camera in my app. im using xcode 11 with swift 5

the error occures in the line below:

```
let usecamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
```

error message:

```
Type 'AVCaptureDevice' has no member 'defaultDevice'
```

I tried the code below but that does not work:

```
 let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera,
    for: AVMediaType.video,
    position: .back)

    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        session.addInput(input)

    }
```

but get the error message:

```
Value of optional type 'AVCaptureDevice?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'AVCaptureDevice'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error 1 fix**

You need to update the line to latest swift

```
let usecamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
```

**Error 2 fix**

As error says `captureDevice` is optional you need to either use `captureDevice!` or safely `guard` , so replace

```
let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera,
for: AVMediaType.video,
position: .back)
```

with

```
guard  let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera,
for: AVMediaType.video,
position: .back) else { return }
```